# Logstash ruby filter loop and data set

Tags: ruby, loops, filter, logstash

I have these raw json data:

```
{
   "data": [
      {"price": 0.04123445},
      {"price": 0.123454}
   ]
}
```

I want to convert them to:

```
{
   "data": [
      {"price": 0.04},
      {"price": 0.12}
   ]
}
```

How can I code this with logstash filter?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
>> hash = {
    "data": [
        {"price": 0.04123445},
        {"price": 0.123454}
    ]
}

>> hash.merge(data: hash[:data].map { |pair| pair.transform_values { |value| value.round(2) } })
{:data=>[{:price=>0.04}, {:price=>0.12}]}
```

Note this does not modify the original hash object. It creates a duplicate with the transformed values.